# Editing migration - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails migration. I have the following migration

```
create_table :patients do |t|
  t.string    :name,      null: false
  t.integer   :age,       null: false
  t.string    :phone,     null: false
  t.string    :ailment,   null: false
  t.datetime  :apointment,  null: false
  t.string    :status,    null: false
end
```

I want to change `datetime` to `date`, but when I alter it, rollback and remigrate, it stays as `datetime`.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you altering and rolling it back?

Comment: I'm changing datatime to date. rake db:rollback, rake db:reset, rake db:migrate

Comment: @Jayk is this last migration or have you created any other migration also after this?

Comment: As you are going going to db reset. try db:drop than db:create & finally rake db:migrate,

I know that db:reset does same, but weirdly it did  the trick for me one time

Comment: Great thanks @MuhammadFaisalIqbal

Answer (score 0):

You can have extra migration to change column type:

```
class AlterAppointmentColumnType < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    change_column :patients, :apointment, :date
  end

  def down
    change_column :patients, :apointment, :datetime
  end
end
```

Do prefer create new migrations if you are already deployed your code.

Answer (score 0):

**In Development:**

`db:rollback` **rollsback only the last `migration`**, so it will work only if it is the last `migration`.

If it is not the last migration, you should **rollback using the specific version(timestamp) of migration**

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20180905201547
```

To get the versions or timestamps, use

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

**In Production:**

**Create a new migration** to change column.

You can create using,

```
rails g migration change_data_type_for_appointment
```

Then in your new migration file:

```
class ChangeDataTypeForAppointment < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :tablename do |t|
      t.change :apointment, :date
    end
  end
  def self.down
    change_table :tablename do |t|
      t.change :apointment, :datetime
    end
  end
end
```

**Reason:**

In development you can migrate down and migrate up because you may alter the data and no problem in increasing the migrations. But in production and data is critical, it is better to create new migrations.